# C++ Cout when calling methods. Dont know what im doing wrong

Tags: c++, class

Im new to coding and im just playing around with C++ trying to learn classes and what not. The this is the following code and i do not know why it doesnt work.

I have Google searched this for a while and cant find anything.

## main.cpp

```
#include "Vehicle.cpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    Vehicle myVehicle();

    cout << myVehicle.testCout();
}
```

## Vehicle.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Engine.cpp"
#include "Body.cpp"
#include "Rims.cpp"

using namespace std;

class Vehicle {

    Vehicle() {
        Engine engine(4, 1.6, "i4");
        Body body("black", 4);
        Rims rims(16);
    }

    void testCout() {
        cout << engine.getCylinders();
    }
};
```

main.cpp:
E0153   expression must have class type ObjectStuff

Vehicle.cpp:
E0020   identifier "engine" is undefined

Comment: Change it to `Vehicle myVehicle;` or `Vehicle myVehicle{};`, then search *most vexing parse*.

Comment: `cout << myVehicle.testCout();` <== what does the `testCout()` method *return* ?? And all those "members" of `Vehicle` are actually automatic variables within the `Vehicle` constructor only. I.e. there is no `engine` in your vehicle. Whatever book/tutorial is showing this stuff to you needs some gas and a flame.

Comment: Not enough code is posted, we can't help without the full picture. You're also including .cpp files in the headers, either you're writing the stuff that should be in a header in the .cpp file, or you're including the wrong file type. However I don't understand why people are mass downvoting this especially because the user claims to be new to the language.

Comment: if you want use `testCout` in `cout` you need to return value from this method. Also you need to have `engine`, `body` and `rims` as class members, not only in constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Vehicle {

    Vehicle() {
        Engine engine(4, 1.6, "i4");
        Body body("black", 4);
        Rims rims(16);
    }

    void testCout() {
        cout << engine.getCylinders();
    }
};
```

The problem is that your instance variable are non-exist. Your constructor creates some variables, but they are deleted after the ctor ends. You need to save them in the class.

```
class Vehicle {
    Engine engine;
    Body body;
    Rims rims;

    public: // And you need to declare the stuff public that you want public
    Vehicle() {
        engine = Engine(4, 1.6, "i4");
        body = Body("black", 4);
        rims = Rims(16);
    }

    void testCout() {
        cout << engine.getCylinders();
    }
};
```

Comment: or something like this `Vehicle() : engine(4, 1.6, "i4"), body("black", 4), rims(16) 
{ }`

Comment: and in `main()` you need to replace this `cout << myVehicle.testCout();` by this `myVehicle.testCout();`

Comment: Wow thanks man. Brain fart I guess haha. I thought I set it up with Member initializers but I guess I forgot here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you've posted a mashup of your actual code but I don't see how you can call private members outside the class.

Why do you include .cpp files?

```
Vehicle.cpp: E0020 identifier "engine" is undefined
```

And the above error is because the compiler can't find the declaration for the Engine class. Likewise for the other objects you're trying to create.